# ¿Problema a consumir un servicio?

Tags: java, api, rest

Buenas noches comunidad stackoverflow

Tengo un problema con una api, en primer lugar tengo que consumir un servicio y solo tiene un parámetro de entrada "audio", como resultado me devuelve un error de formato, "ERROR 400", tengo entendió que esta bien el consumó y además el base64 lo ocupo en postmat y me responde sin problemas.

¿alguien tiene una observación de cual es mi error?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/audio");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("apikey", "XXXXXXXXX");
        String voice = null;
        voice = leerBase64("C:\\Users\\XMY7722_1\\Documents\\python\\BASE64\\VOICE.TXT");
        String input = "{\n"
                + " \"audio\": \"" + voice + "\"}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: `URL url = new URL("URL");` acaso el end point del servicio es `"URL"` debes colocar el endpoint del servicio adecuadamente algo como `http://localhost:8080/sunat/usuario/147` cámbialo y coméntame si tienes algún error para poder ayudarte, si tienes un error coloca si puedes el trace del mismo.

Comment: @Diego-1743, Agregue el end ponit y tienes razón se interpreta de otra manera, el detalle que tengo es el consumo del servicio  me arroja un 400, cuando intento mandar un base64 que corresponde un  audio wav, en postmat y pyhton me responde bien.